# Wait for cordova FileTransfer to be done

Tags: android, ios, cordova, wait

I am downloading the entire app with cordova filetransfer localy on the device and then redirect the index to the downloaded location.

But my issue is that i can't seem to find any solution for waiting for the filetransfer to be done before redirecting.

Her is my code for downloading:

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();


    var downloadUrl = "http://example.com/index.html";
    var relativeFilePath = "example/index.html";
    fileTransfer.download(downloadUrl, localpath = fileSystem.root.toURL() + '/' + relativeFilePath, function(entry) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("Error during download. Code = " + error.code);
        });
```

I am doing so for each file. (approx. 200 files). Maybe there is a better way of doing it, but this works.

I have tried document.ready, $.when().done() but no luck. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: redirect in success callback of filtransfer plugin..

Comment: I can't use the success callback, because i can't define which of the 200 file is downloaded last. If i some how could bundle all 200 in one filetransfer then it wouldn't be a problem. (BTW *.Zip is not a solution, there isen't an extract available for all platforms, which is required in my case)

Comment: If you know total no of files in advance then you can check for condition in success callback using counter variable to conditionally redirect..

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you give me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a solution for this? Have the same problem now